# TableView Inside a UITableViewCell - must register a nib or class

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I'm putting a `UITableView` inside `UITableViewCell`.

I've extended my class of `UITableViewCell` to `,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate`.

Made the `@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!`

Added the following:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style , reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setUpTable()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        setUpTable()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setUpTable()
    }
```

Where as `setUpTable()` is implemented as:

```
func setUpTable(){
        tableView?.delegate = self
        tableView?.dataSource = self
        //tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "AvailableTimingsTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TimingCell")
    }
```

If I keep the commented line in `setUpTable()` I get:

> 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier TimingCell - must register a
>   nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a
>   storyboard'

If I uncomment the comment I get:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on the same line.

After `setUpTable()` I've implemented them as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimingCell", for: indexPath) as?AvailableTimingsTableViewCell

        cell?.dayNameLabel.text = "Wednesday"
        cell?.timeLabel.text = "01:00 PM - 03:00 PM"

        return (cell)!
    }
```

**EDIT** Here are the screenshots of the class names. I've double checked all is okay as per the comments and answer.
[image]
[image]

Comment: are you using custom cell with xib? make sure xib also have same identifier

Comment: @karthikeyan yes I'm using custom cell with xib.

Comment: Check xib identifer also "TimingCell"

Comment: @karthikeyan see my updated question. I'm using everything correct as per my check.

Comment: stop calling setUpTable() from awakeFromNib and check once

Comment: By commenting `setUpTable()` in `awakeFromNib` I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.
If I comment `tableView.register` line from `setUpTable()` it runs fine but I am unable to see the `cell` in tableview.

Comment: retrun some height to row using their protocol and check
and make sure IBOutlet connected and check text color

Comment: Added `heightForRowAt` function and `return 45` in it. Still the same, but I added a breakpoint at this function tells me that by removing `setUpTable()` in `awakeFromNib` it is no longer calling the delegate methods.

Comment: @karthikeyan thank you for the help. the solution is to remove `setUpTable()` from `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` & `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)` now it worked perfectly.

Comment: welcome nice to hear

Answer (score 1):

I think that setUpTable() in the init() is called too soon. At that point view is not loaded. Do that setup in viewDidLoad(), also don't comment out registering the cell. Other than that code looks good.

Comment: Yes the solution is to remove `setUpTable()` from `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` & `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)`

Answer (score 0):

Please check Below points

1) You need to register cell identifier in XIB,

2) Assign Class name to XIB

3) cell for row you need to check with as? YourClass in dequeue and

4) dequeue with same identifier you assign to XIB and register (Here is issue as per me )

Comment: By commenting `setUpTable()` in `awakeFromNib` I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.` If I comment `tableView.register` line from `setUpTable()` it runs fine but I am unable to see the cell in tableview. Other than that the xib and identifier names are okay.

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha  How you can get cell without register it ?, DON'T COMMENT  tableView.register is necessary